# Prove that $A \cap (B \triangle C) = (A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need to prove this:

$$A \cap (B \triangle C) = (A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)$$

I've done Venn Diagrams and they don't seem to be equal.

Plus I want to know how you would do it, because I had to write 2 entire pages using set properties, and the results were bad (not equivalent sets).

Thanks

Comment: Hmm I did a simple Venn Diagrams and it seem to be equal. Are you sure you have the right definition of $\triangle$.

Comment: Indeed.  [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a+and+%28b+xor+c%29) agrees [that they](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a+and+b%29+xor+%28a+and+c%29) are the same.  Remember that $B\triangle C = (B\cap C^c)\cup (B^c\cap C)$

Comment: @Jennifer I did $(A \cap B) \cup (A \cap C) \cap ((A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C) complement)$

Comment: Lefthandside expanded:  $A\cap (B\triangle C) = A\cap ((B\cap C^c)\cup (B^c\cap C)) = (A\cap B\cap C^c)\cup (A\cap B^c\cap C)$

Comment: @JMoravitz I didn't have that equivalence I was using $A \triangle B = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cap B)^{c}$

Comment: @JorgeeFG You can also use $B\triangle C = (B\cup C)-(B\cap C)$.

Comment: $A\triangle B = (A\cup B)\cap (A\cap B)^c$, not what you just wrote.  Either way, I think the way I wrote it on line two is a much easier form to work with.  They are indeed equivalent definitions.  (maybe practice by showing why)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\begin{array}{l} x \in A \cap (B \triangle C) \\ \Rightarrow x \in A \space and \space  x \in (B \triangle C)\\ \Rightarrow  x \in A \space and \space  x \in (B\cup C)-(B\cap C) \\ \begin{array}{ll}\Rightarrow x \in( A \cap(B\cup C))-( A \cap B \cap C)&=(( A \cap B)\cup ( A \cap C))-((A \cap B)\cap (A \cap C)) \\&=(A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)\end{array}\end{array}$.

So $A \cap (B \triangle C)  \subseteq  (A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)$

You can do the other inclusion with the same kind of reasonning.

How did I obtain fourth line, I will show you with a simpler example :

$\begin{array}{l} x \in A \space and \space x \in (B-C)  \\ \Rightarrow  x \in A \space and \space  x \in B \space and \space  x \notin C \\ \Rightarrow  x \in (A \cap B) \space and \space  x \notin (A\cap C) \\ \Rightarrow  x \in (A \cap B)-(A\cap C) \end{array}$

Comment: Consider using `\begin{array}{l} firstline\\ second line\\ ... \end{array}`  Your line is extending well beyond the intended region.

Comment: Ok I will try that thanks !

Comment: For additional typesetting tips, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) has a great deal of information.  If you prefer having the majority of it in the right column like ervx has it above, consider changing to `\begin{array}{ll}firsthalf & secondhalf\\ & secondhalf2\\ ...\end{array}`, or you can rightclick his or anyone else's math and select "show math as: TeX commands"

Comment: Wow thank you so much I watched is latex code but did not understand that the & allowed to separate two parts of the array. I will read carrefully the post about aligning equations.

Comment: I would need more info on what law you used to distribute A in the substraction, if it is possible. Thanks!

Comment: @JorgeeFG I added a simpler example, you should be able to reuse this example in the previous proof.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x \in A \cap (B \triangle C)$. This means that $x \in A$, and also $x \in B \triangle C$, which means that either $x \in B, x \notin C$ or $x \in C, x \notin B$. What happens in either case?

Now try the reverse inclusion as well: $x \in (A \cap B) \triangle (A \cap C)$. Then either $x \in A \cap B$ and $x \notin A \cap C$, or the other way round. 
If $x \in A \cap B$ we already know $x \in A$, $x \in B$, so the only way we can have $x \notin A \cap C$ is when ?, so then $x$ lies in ... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use DeMorgan's laws.

$$
\begin{aligned}
A\cap(B\bigtriangleup C)&=A\cap((B\cap C^{c})\cup(C\cap B^{c}))\\
&=(A\cap(B\cap C^{c}))\cup (A\cap(C\cap B^{c}))\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap C^{c})\cup (A\cap C)\cap B^{c})\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap(C^{c}\cup A^{c}))\cup ((A\cap C)\cap(A^{c}\cup B^{c}))\qquad\text{(Why?)}\\
&=((A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)^{c})\cup ((A\cap C)\cap (A\cap B)^{c})\\
&=(A\cap B)\bigtriangleup(A\cap C)
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: How does the $A ^{c}$ appears?

Comment: $(A\cap B)\cap (C^{c}\cup A^{c})=(((A\cap B)\cap C^{c})\cup((A\cap B)\cap A^{c})))=((A\cap B)\cap C^{c})\cup\emptyset=(A\cap B)\cap C^{c}$

Answer (score 1):

Characteristic functions are useful here. First observe that in general:

- $1_{P\cap Q}=1_P1_Q$
- $1_{P\triangle Q}=1_P+1_Q-1_P1_Q$

Then the answer to your question is just a verification of:$$1_A(1_B+1_C-1_B1_C)=1_A1_B+1_A1_C-1_A1_B1_A1_C$$

Which is a direct consequence of the trivial equality: $$1_A=1_A^2$$

Your "two entire pages" are turned into "two lines".